# CSS selection style removes other styles

Tags: css

I'm working on a text editor with a custom spell checker. It adds a css class around misspelled words to show a red zigzag under the word.

I also use a class to style selections in the editor with a custom background color.

```css
.spell-error {
  background-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBAADAIABAP8AAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAEAAMAAAIFRB5mGQUAOw=="); 
  background-position: bottom; 
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

::selection {
  background-color: #99def7;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background-color: #99def7;
}
```

```html
<p>There is a <span class="spell-error">misstake</span> in this sentence</p>
```

**The issue is when I highlight over a word with `.spell-error` the red zigzag disappears.** I've tried creating a `.spell-error::selection` class but the issue persists. How can I make both classes appear at the same time?

Comment: The code you posted is working for me in Chrome 87 on Windows 10. There does not appear to be a conflict between your `selection` pseudo-element selector and your `spell-error` class.

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `background-image` will have a white background which overlays the background colour.
You need to have a specific background-image for the `.spell-error::selection`, which has the correct background colour in the actual image.